# How to reorder lists for lists based on a certian column value?

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I'm reading a csv file which has data in the form.

```
person,1,125,321,123,532
person,1,123,521,123,632
person,10,324,345,12,456
chair,7000,123,45,12,643
```

I can read it with `my_data = np.genfromtxt(filename,delimiter=",",dtype=None)`
and then I have a ndarray.

I'd like to re order them based on their second column value.
The output should be an ndarray in the form

```
[
[[person,1,125,321,123,532],[person,1,123,521,123,632]]
[person,10,324,345,12,456]
[chair,7000,123,45,12,643]
]
```

My way is to

```
my_data = np.genfromtxt(filename,delimiter=",",dtype=None)
tem = []
for x in range(0,8000,22):
    fake_array=([a_value for a_value in my_data if (a_value[1]==x)])
    if (len(fake_array)>0):
        tem.append(fake_array)
```

This gives me the write result But I feel its a very bad way to do this.
Can anyone suggest me an optimized way to do this??
Especially cause I iterate from 0 to 8000 even though there might be only 10 values.
And nested in this iterating through all rows of the array.

I think the function numpy.unique https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html can be used as well.
I'm not sure how to implement it ?

Comment: Have you tried `sorted(your_array, key= lambda x:x[1])`. It will sort your array, using the index 1.

Comment: @IMCoins that only sorts it but does not make the structure I'd like as in the example.

Comment: You mean the numpy array ? `your_array = np.array( sorted(your_array, key= lambda x:x[1]) )`. I might have misunderstood your problem though.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the python library `pandas` here instead of of trying to do everything in numpy (it's too low level for what you're doing). With pandas you can do want you want via:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by="col_2")
```

Comment: my colums dont have names so I get the error "key_error: col_2"

Comment: if you can modify the csv, I'd recommend giving your columns meaningful names on the first row of the file. pandas knows how to handle csv files in this format and it will come in handy in a lot of other ways in the future.

Comment: Or, just define column names when you read the file in, e.g. `pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', header=None, names=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])`.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this,

```
my_data = my_data[my_data[:,1].argsort()]
```

Comment: this does not work as my_data has the type tuple with shape (1352,)

Comment: Ok. So your code to read the csv file it's not good. Your data must have 6 columns.

Comment: If you run 'my_data.shape' and you had something other than '(N, 6)', so your have something wrong when you code read the csv file, or your file CSV it's not good.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code below:

```
df = pd.read_csv("D:/path/test.csv",header=None,sep=',')
df=df.rename(columns={0:"Name",1:"Value1",2:"Value2",3:"Value3",4:"Value4",5:"Value5"})
df=df.sort_values(by="Value1")
```

You will get the output below:

```
    Name    Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5
0   person  1   125 321 123 532
1   person  1   123 521 123 632
2   person  10  324 345 12  456
3   chair   7000    123 45  12  643
```